# Python: Filter in File I/O

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to take out the strings "a" and "b" from a document. Here's what I am doing but it's not working because I can't use replace in a list.

```
def filter_ab(filename):
    fileRef=open(filename)
    file_list=fileRef.readlines()
    filter="ab"
    for k in file_list:
        for j in k:
        if j in filter:
          file_list=file_list.replace(j,"")
```

Comment: also, I don't want to use read(). I was wondering if there was some way to do this with readlines()

Comment: You don't need `readlines()` even.  Just `for line in file_list:` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use something like this:

```
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('file2.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('a', '').replace('b', ''))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
def filter_ab(filename):
    lines = []
    with open(filename, "r") as fh:
        for line in fh.readlines():
            line = line.replace("a", "")
            line = line.replace("b", "")
            lines.append(line)
    with open(filename, "w") as fh:
        for line in lines:
            fh.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

[str.translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) is actually quite convenient for something like this

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('file2.txt', 'w') as f2:
  for line in f1:
      f2.write(line.translate(None, 'ab'))
```